# Rails ActiveAdmin : undefined method `find' for ActiveAdmin::Page:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I have devise and ActiveAdmin both gem in Gem file.

in initializer, I have active_admin.rb and devise.rb

When I am running /admin, I am getting this error:

/admin/login looks fine.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `find' for ActiveAdmin::Page:Class):
  inherited_resources (1.4.0) lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb:44:in `resource'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:440:in `_run__831531001__process_action__916156029__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:49:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__211781807__call__940431284__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I am pretty sure AA doesn't play well with Inherited Resources

Comment: I don't understand your comment? Can you please try updating active admin & inherited resources to newest versions?

Comment: I updated to latest version and Gemfile for this looks like

gem "devise", "~> 3.0.0"
gem "activeadmin", "~> 0.6.0"
gem "omniauth", "~> 1.1.4"
gem "omniauth-facebook", "~> 1.4.1"

Also I am using devise for regular sire authentication (user.rb) and active admin (admin_user.rb)

Still getting the same error!

Comment: If I were you I'd file a bug on Github for InheritedRecources and ActiveAdmin, I don't think you did anything wrong here. And if you do please add links to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No The issue was mixed with this

I declared few variables (devise specific) in application controller (to use devise as ajax mode) as follows:

<strike>def resource_name
        @resource_name ||= :user
      end</strike>

```
  def resource
    if current_user
      @resource = current_user
    else
      @resource ||= User.new
    end
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

Hence the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael, but I got the solution, this seems issue with the routes. rb **reordering**

Previously it was like

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {sessions: 'sessions', :registrations => 'registrations', :passwords => 'passwords'}

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')

  if Rails.env == 'development'
    root :to => 'public#index'
  else
    root :to => 'public#landing'
  end

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

And after the fix its

```
  if Rails.env == 'development'
    root :to => 'public#index'
  else
    root :to => 'public#splash'
  end

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {sessions: 'sessions', :registrations => 'registrations', :passwords => 'passwords'}
```

Thanks again.